# Programmatically set android:excludeFromRecents in android?

Tags: android

I am able to set android:excludeFromRecents="true" in manifest file for the Launcher activity for an APP in android, and this works fine.However i am not able to do this programmatically.In my class i have tried doing this programmatically using the following code

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Sign_up.this,Logged.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Can some one suggest me what is wrong in the above code.I have tried searching lot for this but haven't got a solution so far.

Comment: do you want the launcher activity to be exclude from recent by programming? or any other activity

Comment: here Logged Activity will be excluded from recents. not Sign_uo Activity...

Comment: @GopalRao,i want the application to be excluded from recents.I was able to do this in Manifest when i android:excludeFromRecents="true" to Launcher activity.